# How to move marked line to current location

Tags: command-line, mark, range

Say I put a mark down somewhere with `ma`. Then I jump somewhere else, `GG3k`. I want to move what's at my mark to the current line.

I could have just `dd`'d it if I'd had some forethought, but is it possible to `:m'a` to my current location somehow? I know I could put down another mark and just `:m'a'b`, but is there an easier/faster way? I thought it might be `.` e.g. `:m'a.` but that didn't do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format for [`:m[ove]`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Am) is

```
:[range]m[ove] {address}
```

Where the range is the line or lines you want to move and the address is the target. Note that the moved line(s) will actually be placed on the line *below* the address.

So you're looking for a range of "mark a" and an address of "the current line". You can find all the special names for ranges and addresses here: [`:h :range`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) aka `:h {address}`.

That tells us that marks are denoted with a `'` followed by the mark name and that the current line is denoted with `.`.

That gives us...

```
:'amove .
```

Or, abbreviated a bit...

```
:'am.
```

---

By the way, you mentioned `:m'a'b`. That actually won't do what you suggest. When you don't specify a range the current line is implied. And when you specify two marks as the address the second one is (apparently) ignored. So that command's full form is `:.move 'a` and it moves the current line below the line marked as `a`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I especially appreciate the note about how what I was trying wouldn't work.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the comment. Cheers.